# ASP.Net Core Web API convention-based routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

What am I missing that I'm greeted with a `404` for this controller? I really don't want to use attribute-based routing. I also don't want `action` to be part of any URIs.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and .Net Core 1.1.

#### TestController.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Foo.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public long Get() => DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    }
}
```

Note that this works with a `[Route("api/Test")]` attribute. But I don't want to use attribute-based routing. And as soon as I take that attribute off, I get 404s.

#### Startup.cs

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "api/{controller}/{id?}"
                    );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Note there's also some stuff in here for Autofac/DI, but I took that out to remove the distraction.

#### Debug output from a request

```
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-03-10T14:18:01.3308908Z","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.0.0","ai.operation.id":"0HL37O0HBESDL","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50129/api/test","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","Host":"localhost:50129","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost","Path":"/api/test","Protocol":"HTTP/1.1","Method":"GET","Scheme":"http"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50129/api/test  
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-03-10T14:18:01.3633954Z","tags":{"ai.cloud.roleInstance":"Desktop","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.0.0","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.operation.id":"0HL37O0HBESDM","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.nodeName":"Desktop","ai.operation.name":"GET /api/test"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Request successfully matched the route with name 'default' and template 'api/{controller}/{id?}'.","severityLevel":"Verbose","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase","RouteName":"default","{OriginalFormat}":"Request successfully matched the route with name '{RouteName}' and template '{RouteTemplate}'.","RouteTemplate":"api/{controller}/{id?}"}}}}
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-03-10T14:18:01.3663952Z","tags":{"ai.cloud.roleInstance":"Desktop","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.0.0","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.operation.id":"0HL37O0HBESDM","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.nodeName":"Desktop","ai.operation.name":"GET /api/test"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"No actions matched the current request","severityLevel":"Verbose","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler","{OriginalFormat}":"No actions matched the current request"}}}}
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-03-10T14:18:01.3693962Z","tags":{"ai.cloud.roleInstance":"Desktop","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.0.0","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.operation.id":"0HL37O0HBESDM","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.nodeName":"Desktop","ai.operation.name":"GET /api/test"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Request did not match any routes.","severityLevel":"Verbose","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware","{OriginalFormat}":"Request did not match any routes."}}}}
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-03-10T14:18:01.3753962Z","tags":{"ai.cloud.roleInstance":"Desktop","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.0.0","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.operation.id":"0HL37O0HBESDM","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.nodeName":"Desktop","ai.operation.name":"GET /api/test"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Connection id \"0HL37O0H95P8K\" completed keep alive response.","severityLevel":"Verbose","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","ConnectionId":"0HL37O0H95P8K","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel","{OriginalFormat}":"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" completed keep alive response."}}}}
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-03-10T14:18:01.3878990Z","tags":{"ai.cloud.roleInstance":"Desktop","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.0.0","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.operation.id":"0HL37O0HBESDM","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.nodeName":"Desktop","ai.operation.name":"GET /api/test"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Request finished in 54.7982ms 404","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","ElapsedMilliseconds":"54.7982","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost","StatusCode":"404"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 54.7982ms 404
```

Comment: @Nkosi Other than some Autofac/DI stuff which I took out, it's exactly like this... No other actions or even methods in this controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not works, as mapping to action method is not defined. AFAIK, you may achieve the WebApi **REST** like routing ONLY using the attribute routing and you may define it on controller level:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public long Get() => DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
}
```

**Update**: have found this github issue [Web API not working with convention based routin](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5791) and:

> for ASP.NET Core MVC we decided to adopt MVC 5.x's conventional routing approach and not Web API 2.x's approach. With the conventional routing approach, **the route must specify both a controller and an action**.

---

You may change route template to

```
template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
```

But in this case, your URL will be `/api/test/get`.

---

**Update 2** (based on the [guide](https://stackify.com/asp-net-core-web-api-guide/)): you can include the NuGet package for [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/) and still use ApiController. The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim) if you are curious as to what it does. Then you can define the WebApi routing:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: @Alex using `template: "api/{controller}/{action}{id?}"` ? but in this case this is not a WebAPI REST style...

Comment: maybe it isn't REST style, but it's possible in ASP.NET Core WebAPI anyway

Comment: Thank you for finding that github issue. I took the cue from your answer and added ```defaults: new { action = "Get" }``` to the route registration in ```Startup.cs```. It is now invoking the controller without ```{action}``` in the routing template. However, if I do that then even HTTP POSTs will invoke that ```Get``` method. Regardless, I think your answer is correct

Comment: @MattThomas have updated answer, as found that it is possible to use WebApi routing behaviour using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim`